# Is switch statement best to ad a selected class to a menu

Tags: javascript

I have a userControl.htm that has the nav links of pages, I have the pages with ID and i want to ad the "selected" class to the corresponding home link.

i thought that var page = (getElementByID("someId"))  will do it but no luck.

```
var page = (getElementByID("someId"))    
switch (page) {
case 'home':
    document.getElementById("About").className = "selected";
    break;
case 'about':
    document.getElementById("About").className = "selected";
    break;
case 'contact':
    document.getElementById("contact").className = "selected";
    break;
case 'services':
    document.getElementById("services").className = "selected";
    break;
default:
    document.getElementById("home").className = "selected";
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Just verifying if this is correct: when you're on the home page, you're on the about page, but when you're on the default page, you're on the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go with jquery

```
    current_page = document.location.href
if (current_page.match(/index/)) {
    $("#home").addClass("selected");
} else if (current_page.match(/Contact/)) {
    $("#contact").addClass("selected");
} else if (current_page.match(/media/)) {
    $("#media").addClass("selected");
} else if (current_page.match(/About/)) {
    $("#About").addClass("selected");

} else if (current_page.match(/Information/)) {
    $("#information").addClass("selected");
} else { // don't mark any nav links as selected
    $("ul#navigation li").removeClass('selected');
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a key-value map instead of writing redundant code:

```
//value with corresponding, and maybe not 1:1 pair
var pairs = {
  'home' : 'About',
  'about' : 'About',
  'contact' : 'contact',
  'services' : 'services',
  'default' : 'home'
  //you can add as much as you want here
};

//then get your page value
var page = getYourValue();

//page might or might not exist on the pairs list, thus we check
//default to 'default' if non-existent
page = (pairs[page]) ? page : 'default';

//then get from the map the desired value
document.getElementById(pairs[page]).className = "selected";
```

You can get the id of the body by using either:

```
document.body.id
//or
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].id
```

Comment: Thank you Joseph, it's going to read the body id and ad the class to the id on the <a href="url"></a> id that i have. i tried getting the value var page = document.getElementById("home"); but it didn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
document.getElementById(page).className = "selected";
```

Instead of that big switch statement, which is just copying your value of the string.

Comment: Hi Doorknob i am doing that right now but that its on every page.
what i want it's to put it on a external script. thank you though